# Testing angular factories with jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, tdd, jasmine

I have a problem with jasmine and angular. I have to test my factories.
I have made simplidfied project on plunker.
Here is demo app:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Agq4xz9NmYeEDWoJguxt
Here is demo test:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ALVKdXO00IEDaKIjMY6u
The first problem is how to make spec runner working without any specification to test.

When you run demo test plunker you will see error:

> TypeError: myDataRaw is undefined in http: //run.plnkr.co/Kqz4tGMsdrxoFNKO/app.js (line 39)

Somebody can help?

Thanks

Comment: Please fix all messed-up variable names first. Rename 'persons' to 'people'. What does this do `var persons  = myDataRaw.persons.person;`? Assigning a person to people collections? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "persons = myDataRaw.persons.person;" indeed results in collection. you can check it on the working example http://plnkr.co/edit/Agq4xz9NmYeEDWoJguxt which is the same code. I have made 2 plunkr's because one is demo and another one the same code but for jasmine test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

In your production code

```
var dataLoadedPromise = $http.get('myData.xml', {transformResponse: transformResponse});
```

you expect the return from the server is `XML` data not json, so when you mock the HTTP, you should use XML instead of Json.

Here is the working code:

```
describe("controller: MyController", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module("myApp");
    });

    var dataFactory;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $controller, $rootScope, $location, $httpBackend) {
        this.$location = $location;
        this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
        dataFactory = $injector.get('dataFactory');

        this.$httpBackend.expectGET('myData.xml').respond(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><myData><persons><person><firstName>Pera</firstName><lastName>Peric</lastName><email>perica@gmail.com</email><score>22</score></person></persons></myData>");

        $controller('MyController', {
            $scope: this.scope,
            $location: $location,
            myData: dataFactory
        });
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        this.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        this.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    });

    describe("successfully parsed persons", function () {
        it("should have 2 persons", function () {

            dataFactory.getData();
            this.$httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Updated Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PAzEDtxfCTbuTqYSYpxu?p=preview)**</kbd>